# Find $\exp(D)$ where $D = \begin{bmatrix}5& -6 \\ 3 & -4\end{bmatrix}. $

Tags: matrices, exponential-function

The question is

> Find $\exp(D)$ where $D = \begin{bmatrix}5& -6 \\ 3 & -4\end{bmatrix}. $

I am wondering does finding the $\exp(D)$ requires looking for the canonical form... Could someone please help?

Comment: this would help [ http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=diagonalize+%7B%7B5%2C-6%7D%2C%7B3%2C%E2%88%924%7D%7D ]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

- Write the Jordan Normal Form (it is diagonalizable) with unique eigenvalues.
- $e^{D} = P \cdot e^J \cdot P^{-1}$

The Jordan Normal Form is:

$$A = P J P^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}1&2 \\ 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}~\begin{bmatrix}-1&0 \\0 & 2\end{bmatrix}~\begin{bmatrix}-1&2 \\ 1 & -1\end{bmatrix}$$

Now use the above formula to find the exponential of $D$.

Comment: is the answer going to be the following $\exp(D)$ where $D = \begin{bmatrix}2e^2 - e^{-1} & -2e^2+2e^{-1} \\ e^2-e^{-1} & -e^2+2e^{-1}\end{bmatrix}. $ ?